# ASP.NET not inserting data into SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

New poster here so bear with me. I am doing a small customer registration/waiting list web app, and most of the program is running well except for one thing... adding data to SQL Server. I've tried everything and nothing works. This is basically my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CustMastTestConnectionString %>"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Turns2] ([CustNum]) VALUES (@CustNum)" >

    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustNum" ControlID="txtInput" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type=String />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Still... it isn't inserting any data at all. I am trying to see what could be wrong but I see nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: THis is my current code for the button press. It seems good to me but it isn't inserting data. I also made sure the columns had enough characters, writable, added an auto increment, etc. I added an entry manually and it worked fine

```
Try
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=CustMast_Test;Integrated Security=True"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)


            cn.Open()

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcctNum", txtInput.Text)
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Turns2] ([AcctNum]) VALUES (@AcctNum)"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()

        End Using
    Catch

    End Try
```

Also tried without ExecuteNonQuery. What is wrong?

Comment: What's triggering your insert?

Comment: You'll need to give more information to go on.  An SqlDataSource doesn't insert data by itself - show the code behind your button press which is being used to call it.  When you say nothing works, do you get any errors?

Comment: To get the most out of SO your questions should show the code you currently have and the errors, if any, that you are receiving.  The words *"I've tried everything"* and *"nothing works"* are by definition inaccurate and devoid of useful content.  The question as is is missing the code that actually uses the sqldatasource and there are no error messages listed.

Comment: *slaps forehead*

It wasn't giving me any errors. It seems I didn't write the codeback in VB. Sorry, pretty new at ASP.

On a second note I have no idea how to call the command. Do I just write a normal "SQL Conn" as one usually does in VB or do I call the SqlSource that is already in ASP? Thanks in advance

Comment: I honestly thought SqlDataSource inserted the data. So, I already have the "codeback" for the button press. Do I need to write a whole new connection or since it already is using a DataSource in ASP do I just call it somehow? Most books only teach you to insert data with things like GridView or DetailsView, so I assumed i just needed an insert.

Comment: Went ahead and worked on the codeback



     `    Try
            Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=CustMast_Test;Integrated Security=True"
            Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)


                cn.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Turns2] ([CustNum) VALUES (@CustNum)"
            End Using
        Catch
`

Still won't insert. Imported namespaces and everything. (Can't for the love of God get it formatted)

Comment: You should post code in question as update and not in comment

Comment: Added the VB Code-behind for the button press. Any help on why its not working would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: Nope. Nothing. It just doesn't add anything to the DB.

Comment: Did you use breakpoints and debug code? remove your try/catch and then run you button click code and see if it throws any exception.

Comment: Eliminated the "ExecuteNonQuery" line, checked a breakpoint and it seems to be grabbing the txtInput data line perfectly. "Cmd" says "Nothing" though.

Comment: Removing Try Catch allowed me to get the ExecuteNonQuery problem, and with breakpoints I checked what was giving me trouble... but the only "weird" thing is cmd saying "Nothing"

Comment: "SCRATCH That.... it is giving me info. CommandText says "" and cmd gives me the ....SQLCommand line.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue solved?  If not, it might be that your SQL Server connection property has autocommit turned off.  If so, your insert is working and being instantly rolled back.  No error, no foul.  Also no data.